# How to use fillna method

Tags: python, pandas

```py
example = {
    'Team':['Australia', 'England', 'South Africa', 'Australia', 'England', 'India', 
            'India', 'South Africa', 'England', 'India','India','Australia'],
    'Player':['Ricky Ponting', 'Joe Root', 'Hashim Amla', 'David Warner', 
              'Jos Buttler', 'Virat Kohli', 'Rohit Sharma', 'David Miller', 
              'Eoin Morgan', 'Dinesh Karthik',np.nan ,np.nan],                  
    'Runs':[345, 336, 689, 490, 989, 672, 560, 455, 342, 376,370,400],
    'Salary':[34500, 33600, 68900, 49000, 98899, 67562, 56760, 45675, 34542, 31176,
              35000, 34000] 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(example)
```

Now I want to replace 'nan' value with 'Joe Root' where Team == 'India'
I have tried following method with no errors:

```py
df.loc[df.Team == 'India'].fillna(value = 'Joe Root')
```

But when i am using the method below, it gives an error:

```py
df.loc[df.Team == 'India'].fillna('Joe Root',inplace = True)
```

Please can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please format you question. Also do not put your text into the question as comments. It might not be noticed by the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the selection like this:

```py
df[df.Team == 'India'] = df[df.Team == 'India'].fillna(value = 'Joe Root')
# selection = selection.fillna(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

your code `df.loc[df.Team == 'India'].fillna('Joe Root',inplace = True)` is slicing the dataframe and then trying to use inplace. i.e. creating temp dataframe and updating it(`inplace = True`). it can return the partial updated dataframe if used like following

```
my_temp=df.loc[df.Team == 'India']
my_temp.fillna('Joe Root',inplace = True)
my_temp
```

the desire here is to update the **df**, so you can try

```
df.loc[df.Team == 'India','Player']=df.loc[df.Team == 'India','Player'].fillna(value='Joe Root')
```